# Unable to get nested XML attribute using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

example XML is as follows

```
<r>
  <a>installed</a>
  <ad>joe</ad>
  <d>2018-08-03</d>
  <ms_a_p>
    <m_a_p>
      <m>some_m_text</m>
      <p>some_p_text</p>
    </m_a_p>
  </m_a_p>
  <pp>more_text</pp>
  <r>text</r>
  <ri>number</ri>
  <ts/>
  <ti>12:56:44.000</ti>
</r>
```

I am able to retrieve the text for the following tags: a, ad, d, pp, r, ri and ti which is great. I am unable to retrieve the text for the 'm' and 'p' tags. I've pasted my python code below. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree = ET.parse('/h/c/D/File')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for rv in myroot.findall('r'):
    a = rv.find('a').text
    ad = rv.find('ad').text
    d = rv.find('d').text
    ri = rv.find('ri').text
    ti = rv.find('ti').text
    ms_a_p = rev.find('mds_a_p')
    m_a_p = ms_a_p.find('md_a_p')
    m = m_a_p.find('m').text

    if a == 'i':
        print d," - ",ad," - ",ri," - ",ti
```

Output looks like this

```
d  -  joe   -  number1  -  some_m_text1  -  ti1
d  -  joe1  -  number2  -  some_m_text2  -  ti2
  File "rRs.py", line 14, in <module>
    m = m_a_p.find('module').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

So it works in two cases but it fails when the third XML match happens. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix my code. In my if a == 'i' loop, I added the following:

```
m = rv.find('ms_a_p/m_a_p/m').text
```

That allowed me to get the text I was looking for. Thanks to anyone who took the time to reply and take a shot at this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing tag `</ms_a_p>`

#### EDIT

I use Python 3.7.4.

Notice that `myroot` already represents `<r>`.

Therefore I used it as such:

```
<r>
  <a>i</a>
  <ad>joe</ad>
  <d>2018-08-03</d>
  <ms_a_p>
    <m_a_p>
      <m>some_m_text</m>
      <p>some_p_text</p>
    </m_a_p>
  </ms_a_p>
  <pp>more_text</pp>
  <r>text</r>
  <ri>number</ri>
  <ts/>
  <ti>12:56:44.000</ti>
</r>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('xml.xml')
**rv** = mytree.getroot()

**# for rv in myroot.findall('r'):**
a = rv.find('a').text
ad = rv.find('ad').text
d = rv.find('d').text
ri = rv.find('ri').text
ti = rv.find('ti').text
ms_a_p = rv.find('ms_a_p')
m_a_p = ms_a_p.find('m_a_p')
m = m_a_p.find('m').text

if a == 'i':
    print(d, " - ", ad, " - ", ri, " - ", ti)
```

**notice that I used `myroot` instead of `rv`**

Comment: The tag is actually there. I made a typo when I edited my example xml data. Sorry about that.

Comment: Based on what I see in your lines noted with '**', myroot will not be defined but rv will. Because of that, the for statement will call 'myroot.findall('r') but myroot is not defined.